# Unable to start spring-boot in jetty and it always defaults to tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jetty

Unable to start spring-boot in jetty even with the following configuration, what is not being configured properly

```
implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}   
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below code in your build.gradle to exclude Tomcat.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

and then to add Jetty dependecy:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty'
```

And this will start your Spring Boot app with Jetty.